# Different ways to “deloop” a (topological) $A_\infty$-algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads, monads, a-infinity-algebras

Let $\varphi:A\to \mathrm{Ass}$ be an $A_\infty$-operad in topological spaces, and let $X$ be an $A$-algebra. I see three possibilities to construct a delooping out of $X$:

1. Rectify $X$ by taking the pushforward $\varphi_!X$, which is now a topological monoid. Now take the classical bar construction $|N(\varphi_!X)|$. This should be the notion of rectification taken from [[Berger/Moerdijk, 2003]](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206094v2).
2. Rectify $X$ by forming the 2-sided bar construction $B(\mathrm{Ass},A,X)$ which is again a topological monoid, and then take the classical bar construction $|N(B(\mathrm{Ass},A,X))|$. This is the description given in [[Basterra et. al., 2016]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07791).
3. We see that the reduced suspension is a right $A$-module functor by the splitting
   $$\Sigma A X \to \Sigma\left(\bigvee_{k\ge 1}X^{\wedge k}\right)\to \Sigma X,$$
   so we can directly form the 2-sided bar construction $B(\Sigma,A,X)$. For $A=\mathcal{C}_1$, this should be the classical description from [[May, 1972]](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/geom_iter.pdf).

Is there any reference comparing these three descriptions? I would expect that (at least for well-pointed $X$), all descriptions agree up to (weak) equivalence?

Comment: Just a quick clarification: you need to take a cofibrant replacement before applying $\phi_!$, right?  If so, then to compare 1. and 2. you can compare the topological monoids.

Comment: According to Berger/Moerdijk, $\varphi_!$ and $\varphi^*$ forms a Quillen adjunction, so in some sense yes, the induced homotopy functor would at first cofibrantly replace $X$. I guess this is the more canonical functor to consider? Is it easy to say what cofibrant $A$-algebras are? I’d expect that at least those with a “cellular decomposition” (start with the trivial $A$-algebra and inductively attach free $A$-algebras along cofibrations of based spaces) are cofibrant?

Comment: It's not so much about being "canonical" as it is about making sure all your constructions preserve homotopy equivalences.  It looks as though BM work in a very general setting. According to nlab, in the topological case the right induced model structure will be cofibrantly generated  by celluar attachments like the ones you descibe. 
 https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofibrantly+generated+model+category

Comment: E.g. suppose your $A_\infty$ algebra has a non-trivial associativity paths,  $(ab)c \to a(bc)$.  Then $\phi_!$ will naively collapse them in order to make the algebra associative.  This will probably change the homotopy type of your space-- which is not what you want to do when you rectify.

Comment: Okay, I agree! So assume $X$ to be cofibrant, and now you claim that on the level of topological monoids, there is a morphism between $\varphi_! X$ and $B(\mathrm{Ass},A,X)$? Maybe this is obvious but I don’t see it. In which direction does it go?

Comment: I think there is a natural transformation $B({\rm Ass},A,-) \to \phi_! -$.  The bar construction is the realization of a simplicial space $B_n(-)$  and you should be able to identify  $coeq(B_1  \to B_0)$  with $\phi_!-$.  This proof is analogous to the homological algebra fact that you can compute $Tor_A(M,N)$ via the bar construction or by resolving $N$.  (Or the equivalent fact for hocolims).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two old papers that address this topic in some detail:  R. W. Thomason. Uniqueness of delooping machines.  \url{https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077313403}
Z. Fiedorowicz.  Classifying spaces of topological monoids and categories. \url{https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374307?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents}.  Thomason's paper compares 2 and my original version of 3 and others.  I haven't looked up Berger and Moerdijk.